# Encoding UTF-16 converted as string

Tags: python

Sorry, I'm new to coding, so if my doubt is silly, pls forgive me.

```
a = "apple"
b = str(a.encode("utf-16")

c = b.decode("utf-16")
print(c)
```

I expect to be printed as apple
But, it shows **AttributeError: str object has no attribute 'decode'**

Yes I can understand I convert it into string to store the encoded on as like it. I can't able to reverse the process..
Is there any solution to reverse back, so to decode it?

Is there any way to reverse string back so it can decode?

Comment: What you've posted is a _syntax_ error, not an attribute error.

Comment: why did you do `str(a.encode("utf-16")`?  You know have the string representation of a `bytes` object, not a `bytes` object. You can decode *bytes into strings*. You can't decode a string, a string is alreaded decoded

Answer (score 1):

You can't use decode() with str type object because as the error states, str type has only encode() but not decode().

You can use decode() with bytes type object.

So instead of converting it into str, you can convert it into bytes and the code will work.

```
a = "apple"
b = bytes(a.encode("utf-16"))
c = b.decode("utf-16")
print(c)
```

Now, if you really need the encoded literals to store in str type. You can do it after decoding.

```
d = str(b)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: why do you have `bytes(a.encode("utf-16"))`? You just need `a.encode("utf-16")`

Comment: Furthermore, `b` is a `str` already, so `d = str(b)` makes no sense. Indeed, `str` will just return the same `str` object in this case

Comment: Just a heads up that `a.encode("utf-16")` is already `bytes`.